# Ошибка putExtra/getExtra

Tags: java, android, kotlin, разработка-игр, mobile-development

Я хочу передать число coin из одной activity в другую. Использую для этих целей putExtra/getExtra. Но это не работает. В чём моя ошибка, что я делаю не так?

Активити 1:

```
buttonYes.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    try {

       int coin = 5;
        Intent intent = new Intent(EndGame.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("coinsKey", coin);
     
    
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
});



//Button Menu
buttonMenu.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(EndGame.this, MainActivity.class);
        int extra = coinsSave.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_COINS_FINAL, coin);
        intent.putExtra("coinsKey", extra);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Активити 2:

```
TextView coinInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coinInt);
Intent intentExtras = getIntent();
   int extras = intentExtras.getIntExtra("coinsKey", 0);
int coins1 = coins + extras;
coinInt.setText(String.valueOf(coins1));
```

Пользователь нажимает кнопку "Да", затем кнопку возврата в меню и в меню должно появиться 5 монет в TextView. Но вместо этого там остаётся по-прежнему 0.

Comment: У Вас строки закомментированы в первой активити!

Comment: Когда они не были закомментированы проблема была всё та же

Comment: приложите ошибки которые возникают в вопрос

Comment: ошибок не возникает. Число не передаётся из одной активности в другую, всё время остаётся 0.

Comment: как вариант - вы сохраняете в память устройства тоже ноль, попробуйте пройтись дебаггером или через логи посмотрите, или в памяти приложения можно проверить

Comment: много лишнего кода, просто покажите как вызываете активность и как принимаете данные

Comment: Изменил описание. Надеюсь стало понятнее

Comment: В коде ошибок нет, не считая неиспользуемого кода. Скорее всего да, вы просто ничего не сохранили в префы или сохранили туда ноль. Покажите как вы в префы записываете данные.

Comment: SharedPreferences coinsSave = EndGame.this.getSharedPreferences("coins", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = coinsSave.edit();
                editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_COINS_FINAL, coin);
                editor.apply();

Comment: Ну? - а где вы это делаете? Отредактируйте вопрос - добавьте код, относящийся к проблеме. Сейчас невозможно проследить цепочку передачи вашего значения. А вообще зачем передавать через интент, если вы сохраняете в именованный преференс - вы можете забрать значение оттуда же в любой активности

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему вы используете разные файлы для хранения и чтения из префов. Получение SharedPreferences из контекста (`context.getSharedPreferences("coins", MODE_PRIVATE)`) создаёт экземпляр привязанный к активити и только в ней доступный. Соответственно, в другой активити вы этот файл прочитать не сможете.

Используйте глобальные префы во всех актвиити. Вот так можно их получить:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в первой активити не сохраняете значение.

```
int coin = 5;
        Intent intent = new Intent(EndGame.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("coinsKey", coin);
```

Тут вы запихиваете значение в в интент, но сам интент никак не испльзуете.